# UFW blocks allowed IP sometimes

Tags: ufw

I have a server with the IP 172.17.11.101. UFW is enabled and when i do "ufw status", i have :

```
Anywhere    ALLOW    172.17.11.102
```

It works fine nearly all the day but sometimes i have a error during 4-5 seconds :

```
Mar 17 23:59:20 server kernel: [124538.209612] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:a5:26:1a:b2:a3:56:a5:1b:69:08:00 SRC=172.17.11.102 DST=172.17.11.101 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=13165 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=60410 DPT=27018 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 17 23:59:20 server kernel: [124538.348414] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:a5:26:1a:b2:a3:56:a5:3d:87:08:00 SRC=172.17.11.102 DST=172.17.11.101 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=23299 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=32052 DPT=27018 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 17 23:59:21 server kernel: [124539.542688] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:a5:26:1a:b2:a3:56:a5:58:76:08:00 SRC=172.17.11.102 DST=172.17.11.101 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=5814 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=30235 DPT=27018 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 17 23:59:22 server kernel: [124540.320007] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:a5:26:1a:b2:a3:56:a5:28:05:08:00 SRC=172.17.11.102 DST=172.17.11.101 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57844 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64450 DPT=27018 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

We can see that UFW blocks the IP 172.17.11.102.

I don't know how to debug this problem  which happens 2-3 times each days.

Do you have any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Running a port finder for port [27018](https://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/27018) indicates that this is caused by **steam** running on `172.17.11.102`. 
This is confirmed by the steam [website](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711)

```
Required Ports for Steam

Which ports do I need to open on my router or firewall for Steam?
To log into Steam and download content:

HTTP (TCP port 80) and HTTPS (443)
UDP 27015 through 27030
TCP 27015 through 27030
```

So you could for example deactivate/reconfigure steam or deactivate logging  for UFW similar to [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71613/how-can-i-disable-ufw-logging-for-a-specific-event) i.e.:

```
sudo ufw deny 27018
```